# Copying entire project structure into another directory using afterbuild task

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I want to use the `AfterBuild` target for copying the entire project structure into a separate folder. This is the project structure

```
TANKProject  
|
|__TANK.CLI
|__TANK.Core
|__TANK.Web
```

I want to copy the entire project structure including `bin` folder and the `.sln` folder into a location `B:\animesh\repos`.

To do that, I put the following snippet in the `AfterBuild` target in each `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_CustomFiles Include="..\TANK.ProjectName\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(_CustomFiles)"
    DestinationFiles="B:\repos\TANK"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

I get the following error while building the project:

```
"DestinationFiles" refers to 3 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 1 item(s). They must have the same number of items.
```

What am I missing here?

---

### Solution

Based on AdrianMonk's answer, I changed my `AfterBuild` configuration like this:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="..\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy 
      SourceFiles="@(_CustomFiles)" 
      DestinationFiles="@(_CustomFiles->'B:\repos\TANK\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```

I put this `AfterBuild` target in only one of the projects since that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `DestinationFolder`, not `DestinationFiles`:

```
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(_CustomFiles)"
    DestinationFolder="B:\repos\TANK"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

However, this will only copy the files from the root of you project structure. To copy the whole structure including files in subdirectories, you need to use:

```
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(_CustomFiles)"
    DestinationFiles="@(_CustomFiles->'B:\repos\TANK\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

This will do a recursive copy of the entire project structure (also including the output directories). For more information, refer to the [MSBuild Copy task reference docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx).

Comment: This has copied all files from all three projects into `B:\repos\TANK` without any folder structure (http://i.stack.imgur.com/OgHGs.png). I suspect the problem is with the `<ItemGroup>` declaration as: `<_CustomFiles Include="..\MSB.CLI\*.*" />` which seems to say "Copy only all files inside this folder"

Comment: I changed the `<ItemGroup>` to :`<_CustomFiles Include="..\**" />` in only one of the projects and was able to mirror everything inside the project into the destination folder. I edited my answer to add what worked for me.