# MSBuild: How to disable / turn off batching?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have an item group an MSBuild project that represents files to be copied.
The Copy Task, and another custom task I wrote seems to want to batch on the Destination item meta data. I can't help  but wonder that this would be slow, and I'm trying to get this happen as quickly as possible.

So batching means that if a group of 100 items is sent to the task, that the task is NOT called once with 100 items. Instead it is called multiple times with smaller groups of items.

This results in a huge waste of time as the Execute virtual function of the task is hit dozens if not hundreds of times.

How do I disable batching in MSBuild for a Task? Or a target?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of items, you can't really disable batching, but it depends on the task/target you want to call. For example if you use a Copy task, it depends on the destination, if you want to define one target folder or a specific target file for each file to copy.

If you have a custom task, it depends on the implementation of the task, if you could give the input as semicolon separated list or item by item.

Here [MSBuild copy entire directory while using metadata in path names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540562/msbuild-copy-entire-directory-while-using-metadata-in-path-names)  some differences on batching are explained.

If you have more concrete examples of issues please tell.